# Problema ao rodar script externo

Tags: javascript, html

Boa tarde

Estou a aprender as base de construção de uma página web e nesta fase a estrutura da mesma é

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="script/download.js"></script> 
<title>
A Simple HTML Document
</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is a very simple HTML document</p>
<p>It only has two paragraphs</p>
</body>
</html>
```

onde tenho um ficheiro javascript na pasta script e a página estou a abri-la localmente

o ficheiro javascript é

```html
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = 'http://server/file.exe';
link.download = '';
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
```

acontece que quando tento abrir a página web nenhum download é feito
Qual poderá ser o erro aqui?

Obrigado

Comment: Vc tá executando o código antes de existir um `body`. Provavelmente no console está aparecendo o erro: `Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null`

Comment: com efeito na consola diz
TypeError: document.body is nulldownload.js:4:1
    <anónimo> file:///C:/Users//site/script/download.js:4

Comment: peço desculpa por esta pergunta básica, mas qual é o motivo do erro?

Comment: Expliquei na resposta. Abs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como seu script está no `<head>`, ele será executado antes do navegador construir o `body`, e você está tentando acessar o `body` que ainda não existe no DOM, resultando no erro:

> Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

O JavaScript sempre retorna erro quando você tentar acessar uma propriedade (na verdade o `appendChild()` é um método) de um objeto que não existe (`null`).

O que você pode fazer é executar o código dentro de um evento que aguarda o DOM ser carregado:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   var link = document.createElement('a');
   link.href = 'http://server/file.exe';
   link.download = '';
   document.body.appendChild(link);
   link.click();
});
```

Ou então carregar o script no final do `body`:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>
         A Simple HTML Document
      </title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>This is a very simple HTML document</p>
      <p>It only has two paragraphs</p>
      <script src="script/download.js"></script> <!-- CARREGA AQUI -->
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado. Ambas as soluções funcionaram :)

Comment: Saiba como agradecer no [tour]. Abs!